# why click event is not happening on table row?

Tags: android-widget, android-layout

Programmatically I am creating tablelayout and also adding rows to it. But when I clicked on table row its not getting clicked.

In every row I am adding textview and Imageview.I have set onclickListener to tablelayout.

```
TextView txt = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
String stTitle = txt.getText().toString();
int index = strTitle.indexOf(stTitle);
Log.d("AllFeat", " index "+index);
Log.d("AllFeat", " title "+stTitle);
int id  = nId.get(index); 
Intent i = new Intent(CatalogPage.this,AllFeats.class); 
i.putExtra("id", id);
i.putExtra("title",stTitle);
startActivity(i);
```

The above code I am writing in tablelayout.setOnclickListener.

Answer (score 0):

First you can set rowId using setId(nt).After calling setcontentview(view) .findViewById and setOnclickListener();

Comment: thanks.  Now I am creating table rows programatically.In each row there is imageview and textview.I m setting these value when I create imageview & textview and then adding it to row and adding that row to tablelayout. I m having button like "sortByName" and when I click on it I want to set imageview & textview to be set by new values so , again will I have to create table rows and have to add it to table ?